# How can I create a precise touch in Unity

Tags: unity, raycasting

Is there a way so that I can touch an object precisely?

I have these aerial cars and there pretty tiny like 32 by 32 and it's hard to touch them using a raycast. I thought I'd spawn an object with a circle collider on it on the first touch and destroy it after the touch.

Answer (score 1):

A collider probably isn't the best way to solve this issue.

The first thing I'd consider is the size of the cars. It's hard to infer from just the information in the question, but have you considered if the cars are just too small for users to easily manipulate? Raycasts are little imprecise for touches, but if the cars are too small, even with a spherical check you might find that it's not too easy to move them.

If you find that the size of the cars is acceptable, or you can't change the size, you can move on to changing the method you use to detect the touches. Unity has several methods of casting for objects all documented in the [`Physics`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) class.

These include [`Physics.SphereCast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html), which is similar to [`Physics.Raycast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), but allows you to specify a radius for the check in addition to the other parameters.

[`Physics.SphereCastAll`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastAll.html) is similar to [`Physics.SphereCast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html), but returns all objects that were hit, not just the first one. This is mirrors the fact that a single touch can overlap multiple objects.

Note that [`Physics.Raycast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) by default has settings enabled that cause it to return hits on Colliders you set up as Triggers (This can be turned off). The two functions I mentioned above have no such setting, and cannot be configured to hit Triggers. This could be an issue if your current setup requires the cars have Triggers. To get around that you could use [`Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html) and [`Physics.IgnoreCollision`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html).

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problem and decided to use third party assets. My advice is to use EasyTouch. It's pretty good.